# passing values from ios to javaScript

Tags: javascript, ios

iam working on iOS project and there is a statistics page is already done with JS and when loading it into UIWebView everything works fine with a nice Animation

```
[WebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

and the JS code is executed in document.Ready when the DOM is ready..

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
var s1 = [[2002, 112000], [2003, 122000], [2004, 104000], [2005, 99000] ];
});
```

My problem is the data is generated in IOS and i want to pass this data to the JS to draw the chart with a nice animation,,i didn't find a way to pass a parameter to document.Ready so i make this a function and in IOS call this function and pass the parameters...
 so i changed my code to ..

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{ 
 NSString * param  = @"foo";
 NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc('%@')",param];
 [webViewstringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
 [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];
}
```

and the JS to

```
function myFunc (var x) { 
var s1 = [[2002, 112000], [2003, 122000], [2004, 104000], [2005, 99000] ];
};
```

doing that actually passing parameters BUT the animation doesn't appear anymore for reason i don't know and i have tried this with lots of online ready jS charts when i change the function from document.Ready to another function gets called by IOS they **appear** but don't **animate** ....So is there is anyWay to pass a parameters to document.Ready ??

Answer (score 1):

It's not easiest to send your data generated in iOS directly at the beginning? I mean, when you load your UIWebView, you can sent in parameters (POST or GET) your values.

Comment: u mean if i send values with post or Get i will be able to use them in document.REady() function ? can u please write a very very sample code so that i get what u mean ..thanks in advance.